# How to get storybook to display typescript types in stories

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, storybook

Storybook tells us how to write a basic story using typescript.

```
// Button.stories.ts|tsx

// ... Your imports go here

export default {
  /*  The title prop is optional.
  * See https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-loading
  * to learn how to generate automatic titles
  */
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

// We create a “template” of how args map to rendering
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

// Each story then reuses that template
export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = { backgroundColor: '#ff0', label: 'Button' };
```

What it doesn't tell us, or at least it's not obvious to me, is how to get the typescript types inside the story arguments.

```
Primary.args = { 
  // Here 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by changing ComponentMeta and ComponentStory imports to Meta and explicitly defining the story type.

```
// Button.stories.ts|tsx

// ... Your imports go here

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
} as Meta<ButtonProps>;

const Template: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Primary: Story<ButtonProps> = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = { // Start typing your property here, or fire the IDE intellisense };
```